# Begin BigQuery query job without fetching rows on google-cloud-bigquery 0.28.0 python library

Tags: python, google-bigquery

[google-cloud-bigquery 0.28.0](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/releases/tag/bigquery-0.28.0) python library introduced many breaking changes. By looking at the [migration documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/python-client-migration) there are some examples on [how to run queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/python-client-migration#query).

Question is: how can one `begin` a job and synchronously wait for completion (`state="DONE"`) without fetching the results? This is useful for jobs with big outputs and a configured `destination` table.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by fetching results but when you run a query job (`query_job = bqclient.query(query, config)`) the job starts automatically but it does not fetch any results. If you want to wait for results and fetch them then you could run `results = list(query_job.result())`  but other than that the operation is done asynchronously already.

Comment: Thanks! `bqclient.query()` was what I was looking for.